# How to display the count (number of balls) on each sides?

Tags: java

I wrote a program to play Maxwell's Demon. It should have a window with 2 sides and a few

dots running around bouncing off the walls.  There's a wall in the middle.  When you click a

button, a gap opens up in the wall (until you unclick).  This should allow a person to try

to get more balls on one side than the other.  You can display the count on each side.

This is the main class, I have two other classes one is Dot ( where I make my dots move, and

tell how fast), and the other one is BLueDot(where i create the blue dots).

So what I want is that to display the counts of the balls on each sides? Or How many we

got (balls) on each side of the walls?

Main Program

```
package dotChaser;

//DotChaser.java

//This program does some simple animation where a dot move around

//the blue dots.

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DotChaser extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{

 javax.swing.Timer time; // generates ticks that drive the animation
 protected double deltaT = 0.020; // how much time for each tick
 BlueDot[] blues; // holds the blue dots
 int blueCounter = 0; // number of blue dots
 //Label howMany =  new Label();
 JTextField tf;// The text field for the key listener 
 boolean open; // open= true part. pass through, open = false part. dont pass through


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DotChaser d = new DotChaser();
}
// constructor
public DotChaser()
{
   Dot.theDotChaser = this;
   //time managment
    time = new javax.swing.Timer((int)(1000*deltaT), this);
    time.start();

    blues= new BlueDot[200] ;


    tf = new JTextField("---------------");
    add(tf);
    tf.addKeyListener(this);

    for(int i = 0; i<20; i++)
    {blues[blueCounter++] = new BlueDot();

    //count++;                                     
    //howMany.setText(ballReport());

    setLayout( new FlowLayout());
    setTitle("Dot Chaser!");
    setSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    setVisible(true);}


}

// the work its doing 
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
     if (e.getSource()==time){doTime();}
     repaint();
 }
 // key listener mouse motion 
 public void keyTyped( KeyEvent k ) { }
 public void keyPressed( KeyEvent k ) 
 {
      System.out.println("you pressed key="+k.getKeyChar());
      open=true;

 }

public void keyReleased( KeyEvent k ) 
{
    System.out.println("you released key="+k.getKeyChar());
    open=false;
}



// the clock ticked, so tell all the dots to move a little
public void doTime()
{

    for (int i= 0; i<blueCounter; i++)
    {
    blues[i].move(deltaT);
    }

}
 // make another blue dot (and add it to the blues array)
 public void doMoreDots()
 {blues[blueCounter++] = new BlueDot();}


// paint all the dots
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    for (int i= 0; i<blueCounter; i++)
    {
        blues[i].drawMe(g);
    }

     {
      // draw the wall
      g.setColor( Color.pink );
      g.fillRect( 250, 40, 90, 200 );
      g.fillRect( 250, 400, 90, 300 );

    }
    // close wall when false
    if ( open == false)
    {
        g.fillRect(250, 200, 90, 200);
        g.fillRect(250, 400, 90, 300);
    }

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am getting you need to count the total number of dots each side.

The total number of dots you can get from the Array where you are keeping.Add a counter in the below method which will keep the number of dots total.

```
static int count=0;
public void doMoreDots()
 {
    blues[blueCounter++] = new BlueDot();
    count++;
 }
```

Now ,you need to find out the count for each side,here I will suggest that use another 2 separate counter in that class where you can track moving dots.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Um what do you mean by another 2 separate counter, how would that be? Is it like in the same class my main class add two other methods? just like the doMoreDots() one? If you dont mind showing me.

Comment: I added the count++; but it is not giving me the total number of dots?